# Oracle SQL retrieve all associated records

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies for the lame title, I simply don't know how to frame the question.

As you can see from the attached image, I have a resource, and that resource has an approval group associated with it. The relationship between the Resource and Approval group is 1:1, no problem, I can retrieve with a join. But there can be N number of Owners of that approval group, and N number of users in the approval group. I need to pull back all of the owners of the group, and all of the user of group, and have owners and approvers collected in a their respective columns. I need a result set in a single row that has the Resource, the Approval group, ALL of the owners in single column, and ALL of the members in a single column.

[image]

Comment: What data type do you envision "all of the owners" and "all of the members" being?  A comma-separated list?  A JSON array?  An Oracle collection?  Something else?

Comment: @JustinCave, comma separated list. The IDs of the groups owners and group members are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `listagg` function.

I'm making some wild guesses about what your data model looks like.  One option would be two inline subqueries

```
select r.resource_name,
       ag.approval_group_name,
       (select listagg(o.owner_name, ',') 
                 within group( order by o.owner_name )
          from owner_group og
               join owner o on (og.owner_id = o.owner_id )
         where og.group_id = ag.group_id ) all_owners,
       (select listagg(m.member_name, ',') 
                 within group( order by m.member_name )
          from member_group mg
               join member m on (mg.member_id = m.member_id)
         where og.group_id = ag.group_id ) all_members
  from resource r
       join approval_group ag
         on r.group_id = ag.group_id
```

Depending on the sizes of the tables and how performance critical this query is, you could do all the joins in the outer query and just do two `listagg` expressions in the `select` list.  You'd just need to add a `row_number()` to both 1:n expressions that you can join on to ensure that you don't have n owner rows * m member rows per resource.  That's certainly possible but it makes the overall query more complicated-- I'd prefer a simple query unless you have performance issues with it.